# Understanding DebugDiag Tool

Tags: iis, debugdiag

I have been trying to understand what is the cause of high memory usage from processes in the windows server I have. I installed that tool DebugDiag 1.2 to try to find the problem.

Here is what runs in my server:
I have the IIS server which has a decent number of pool applications (68 pool applications). For each pool application there are at least 4 applications.
Recently, I have faced problems related to high memory usage, causing the server to work at 97% of memory usage or higher.

It was working fine when I took this printscreen below. However, the memory usage will easily get higher.

Task Manager:
[image]

With that being said, I have been trying to understand how to use the tool "DebugDiag1.2" from microsoft to find something (part of the source code, an sql procedure) that might help me locate what is causing the problem.

I read that we can't limit the memory for each IIS pool application, so I guess the solution would be trying to optmize the application. But first I need to know where to start.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to learn from Microsoft Support. This is not that kind of knowledge you can easily learn from the web.

Comment: Try this article https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool